# ound this in Where to edit Custom Content fields to optional if there is no plug in?

Tags: plugins, custom-content

I am having 3 custom contents on my front page. Each of them must have an image. However, I want some of them not to have the image, I want to have that field optional.

Any idea where may I change it? I couldn't find any plug in related to that. Only in theme theme folder there is plug in: `advanced-custom-fields` but I can't find it through wordpress.

The theme is custom, made by another guy so I am not really familiar with that.

[image]

I have found this in acf-flexible-content/view directory:

```
<tr class="required">
<td class="label"><label><?php _e("Required?",'acf'); ?></label></td>
<td>
    <?php 
    do_action('acf/create_field', array(
        'type'  =>  'radio',
        'name'  =>  'fields[' .$fake_name . '][required]',
        'value' =>  $sub_field['required'],
        'choices'   =>  array(
            1   =>  __("Yes",'acf'),
            0   =>  __("No",'acf'),
        ),
        'layout'    =>  'horizontal',
    ));
    ?>
</td>
</tr>
```

But I guess this is html which is shown upon creation of a field for custom content.

Comment: [ACF can be included within a theme](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/). The theme should contain code that registers the fields, which you can modify to change options, you'll have to search your theme files to figure out where that code is.

Comment: All right, I have done a little search already but I don't really know what to look for. There is loads of code but all of it seems to be just standard functionality... I will do the search once again. If by any chance you know what should I look for, please let me know :).

Comment: look for either `register_field_group` in your theme files, or an `acf-json` directory inside your theme directory.

Comment: I have found files : "field-group.js" and "field-group.min.js" I am going to check them out and keep you updated so then you can create an actual answer and I will be able to mark it as correct one. Thank you. :)

Comment: I found the function `register_field_group` in `plugin-loaders.php` file. You were right. Please create an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should copy plugin from theme folder to plugin directory and activate it.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry. I misunderstand you.

> I want to have that field optional

It's needed to change theme php code. The task will be easier if you publish this code.

I guess there is registered `save_post` hook in the theme code. And this hook checks if image is present. But I can't give fine answer because I don't know what is really written in your theme code.

Comment: Maybe you want to explain how. Also I'm not sure if that is the best advice. Looking up the specific version and explaining how to fetch _exactly that version_ into the plugins dir might be more beneficial for the OP.

Comment: But since that custom content already works, I am assuming that some settings should be somewhere in the WP right?